# Cardano-Node Preprod Testnet PeerStatusChangeFailure on Mac

Tags: cardano-node, testnet, preprod

I am trying to run Cardano-node with preprod testnet configuration files from :

```
curl -O -J https://book.world.dev.cardano.org/environments/preprod/config.json
curl -O -J https://book.world.dev.cardano.org/environments/preprod/db-sync-config.json
curl -O -J https://book.world.dev.cardano.org/environments/preprod/submit-api-config.json
curl -O -J https://book.world.dev.cardano.org/environments/preprod/topology.json
curl -O -J https://book.world.dev.cardano.org/environments/preprod/byron-genesis.json
curl -O -J https://book.world.dev.cardano.org/environments/preprod/shelley-genesis.json
curl -O -J https://book.world.dev.cardano.org/environments/preprod/alonzo-genesis.json
```

I am using node version 1.35.3 on MacOS Monterey 12.4 using the command :

```
cardano-node run \                                                            
--config $HOME/cardano/preprod/config.json \
--database-path $HOME/cardano/preprod/db/ \
--socket-path $HOME/cardano/preprod/db/node.socket \
--host-addr 0.0.0.0 \
--port 1337 \
--topology $HOME/cardano/preprod/topology.json
```

I tried to change the host-addr and downloaded all the config files for preprod but still getting this error :

```
[ip-192-1:cardano.node.Server:Notice:56] [2022-10-20 13:37:56.26 UTC] TrServerStarted [0.0.0.0:1337]
[ip-192-1:cardano.node.LocalRootPeers:Info:54] [2022-10-20 13:37:56.26 UTC] TraceLocalRootDomains [(1,fromList [])]
[ip-192-1:cardano.node.PeerSelection:Notice:55] [2022-10-20 13:37:56.27 UTC] TraceTargetsChanged (PeerSelectionTargets {targetNumberOfRootPeers = 0, targetNumberOfKnownPeers = 0, targetNumberOfEstablishedPeers = 0, targetNumberOfActivePeers = 0}) (PeerSelectionTargets {targetNumberOfRootPeers = 100, targetNumberOfKnownPeers = 100, targetNumberOfEstablishedPeers = 50, targetNumberOfActivePeers = 2})
[ip-192-1:cardano.node.LocalRootPeers:Info:54] [2022-10-20 13:37:56.26 UTC] TraceLocalRootGroups (fromList [(1,fromList [])])
[ip-192-1:cardano.node.PeerSelection:Info:55] [2022-10-20 13:37:56.27 UTC] TracePublicRootsRequest 100 0
[ip-192-1:cardano.node.LedgerPeers:Info:50] [2022-10-20 13:37:56.27 UTC] [String "FetchingNewLedgerState",Number 0.0]
[ip-192-1:cardano.node.LedgerPeers:Info:50] [2022-10-20 13:37:56.27 UTC] [String "FallingBackToBootstrapPeers"]
[ip-192-1:cardano.node.LedgerPeers:Info:50] [2022-10-20 13:37:56.27 UTC] [String "UseLedgerAfter",Number 4642000.0]
[ip-192-1:cardano.node.PublicRootPeers:Info:60] [2022-10-20 13:37:56.27 UTC] TracePublicRootRelayAccessPoint [RelayAccessDomain "preprod-node.world.dev.cardano.org" 30000]
[ip-192-1:cardano.node.PublicRootPeers:Info:60] [2022-10-20 13:37:56.27 UTC] TracePublicRootRelayAccessPoint [RelayAccessDomain "preprod-node.world.dev.cardano.org" 30000]
[ip-192-1:cardano.node.PublicRootPeers:Info:60] [2022-10-20 13:37:56.34 UTC] TracePublicRootResult "preprod-node.world.dev.cardano.org" [(3.72.231.105,60)]
[ip-192-1:cardano.node.PeerSelection:Info:55] [2022-10-20 13:37:56.34 UTC] TracePublicRootsResults (fromList [3.72.231.105:30000]) 0 60s
[ip-192-1:cardano.node.PeerSelectionCounters:Info:55] [2022-10-20 13:37:56.34 UTC] PeerSelectionCounters {coldPeers = 1, warmPeers = 0, hotPeers = 0}
[ip-192-1:cardano.node.PeerSelection:Info:55] [2022-10-20 13:37:56.34 UTC] TracePromoteColdPeers 50 0 (fromList [3.72.231.105:30000])
[ip-192-1:cardano.node.ConnectionManager:Info:65] [2022-10-20 13:37:56.34 UTC] TrConnectionManagerCounters (ConnectionManagerCounters {fullDuplexConns = 0, duplexConns = 0, unidirectionalConns = 0, inboundConns = 0, outboundConns = 0})
[ip-192-1:cardano.node.ConnectionManager:Info:65] [2022-10-20 13:37:56.48 UTC] TrConnectionManagerCounters (ConnectionManagerCounters {fullDuplexConns = 0, duplexConns = 0, unidirectionalConns = 0, inboundConns = 0, outboundConns = 1})
[ip-192-1:cardano.node.ConnectionManager:Info:66] [2022-10-20 13:37:56.63 UTC] TrConnectionHandler (ConnectionId {localAddress = 172.27.228.239:1337, remoteAddress = 3.72.231.105:30000}) (TrError OutboundError (MuxError MuxBearerClosed "<socket: 30> closed when reading data, waiting on next header False") ShutdownPeer)
[ip-192-1:cardano.node.ConnectionManager:Info:66] [2022-10-20 13:37:56.63 UTC] TrConnectionManagerCounters (ConnectionManagerCounters {fullDuplexConns = 0, duplexConns = 0, unidirectionalConns = 0, inboundConns = 0, outboundConns = 0})
[ip-192-1:cardano.node.ConnectionManager:Info:65] [2022-10-20 13:37:56.63 UTC] TrConnectionManagerCounters (ConnectionManagerCounters {fullDuplexConns = 0, duplexConns = 0, unidirectionalConns = 0, inboundConns = 0, outboundConns = 0})
[ip-192-1:cardano.node.PeerSelectionActions:Error:65] [2022-10-20 13:37:56.63 UTC] PeerStatusChangeFailure (ColdToWarm Nothing 3.72.231.105:30000) (HandleFailure (MuxError MuxBearerClosed "<socket: 30> closed when reading data, waiting on next header False"))
[ip-192-1:cardano.node.PeerSelection:Info:55] [2022-10-20 13:37:56.63 UTC] TracePromoteColdFailed 50 0 3.72.231.105:30000 6.615296391013s (MuxError MuxBearerClosed "<socket: 30> closed when reading data, waiting on next header False")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preprod environment is currently is being relaunched, so you need to wait at least 2 more days from today(20-Oct-2022).

https://t.me/SPOannouncements/227

Comment: Can you help me on how to use RPC calls on the preprod testnet server